# Grabbing value from radio button without using laravel

Tags: php, laravel

So I'm trying to make a post request form which sends data to an API. How can I grab the value from the radio button?

I can't seem to find anything about it online.

**P.S I'm not using the HTML Form function**

Thanks.

**Edit: This is what I'm looking for**

```
<input type="radio" name="package" value="!!THIS!!">
```

Comment: Did you look at the requests doc? https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/requests

Comment: Yes, describes nothing.

Comment: `$request->input('package')` isn't what you're looking for?

Comment: Would that still return the value inside radio button?

Comment: Well yeah, why not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$request->request->get('package');` or `$request->package;` by using [Laravel Requests](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/requests)